# Warning: replacing previous import ‘head’ when loading ‘utils’ in R

Tags: r, cran

When loading the [RTextTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RTextTools/index.html) package from CRAN, I get the following warnings:

> Warning messages:
>   1: replacing previous import ‘head’ when loading ‘utils’
>   2: replacing previous import ‘tail’ when loading ‘utils’

How do I get rid of these warnings? I'm the author of the package, so I can manipulate the source code; I'm looking for a solution that gets rid of the warnings rather than suppresses them. They seem to have appeared when I upgraded to R 2.14. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is not your issue - it's an issue in the `glmnet` package that you depend on: it explicitly imports all functions from both `Matrix` and `utils` but in the wrong order which causes a conflict since they both define `head` and `tail` (Matrix depends on utils so utils must be first). It is easy to fix - the order of imports has to be reversed in the `glmnet/NAMESPACE` but only the maintainer of `glmnet` can do that.

PS: This would be better asked on R-devel

Comment: Thank you Simon! I'll redirect such questions to R-devel in the future.

Answer (score 27):

In general, this problem is often caused by having `import(somepackage)` in the namespace as well as `importFrom(somepackage, somefunction)`.

Equivalently, using `roxygen2`, having both `#' @import somepackage` and `#' @importFrom somepackage somefunction`.

The best practice solution is to remove the `import` statement and keep only `importFrom`.