# Dealing with intentional NAMESPACE conflicts

Tags: r, r-package, dbplyr, name-collision

I'm writing a package that imports (and uses) both `SparkR::sql` and `dbplyr::sql`. The other [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325231/when-writing-my-own-r-package-i-cant-seem-to-get-other-packages-to-import-corr) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662285/warning-replacing-previous-import-head-when-loading-utils-in-r) involve *unintentional* collisions brought on my haphazard `import`ing.

In my `NAMESPACE` I have:

```
importFrom(dbplyr, sql)
importFrom(SparkR, sql)
```

Both of these functions are used in the script and, being aware of the conflict, I'm sure to always prefix the package name:

```
dbplyr::sql(...)
SparkR::sql(...)
```

Nevertheless, I get an import replacement warning when building/checking the package:

> Warning: replacing previous import ‘dbplyr::sql’ by ‘SparkR::sql’ when loading ‘my_pkg’

What I see in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces) seems to be the following:

> If a package only needs a few objects from another package it can use a fully qualified variable reference [`foo::f`] in the code instead of a formal import... This is slightly less efficient than a formal import and also loses the advantage of recording all dependencies in the `NAMESPACE` file (but they still need to be recorded in the `DESCRIPTION` file). Evaluating `foo::f` will cause package `foo` to be loaded, but not attached, if it was not loaded already—this can be an advantage in delaying the loading of a rarely used package.

Am I right that the takeaway of this / best practice is to:

- Pick which function is used most often and add that to `importFrom`
- Remove the "less-frequent" function from `importFrom` but keep that package in `DESCRIPTION`
- Just use `::` (perhaps preceded by `require()`) for the "less-frequent" function

Comment: I think (especially in this case) that I'd always use the `::` notation, even if one is explicitly in `NAMESPACE` ... for clarity if nothing else. I agree that it seems counter-intuitive to be told "you should put it in `NAMESPACE`" and then get the warning when it's an intentional thing. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

I have always followed [this advice](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html):

> It’s common for packages to be listed in Imports in DESCRIPTION, but not in NAMESPACE. In fact, this is what I recommend: list the package in DESCRIPTION so that it’s installed, then always refer to it explicitly with pkg::fun().

In your case:

- Remove *both* `importFrom`
- Keep both packages in `Imports:`
- Use `dbplyr::sql` and `SparkR::sql`

My main motivation here is consistency: Even without any name clashes I want to always use the full name to make it clear when *reading the code* where some function comes from. If I do not use `importForm` and forget about using the full name at one place, `R CMD ckeck` will catch that. I value this code clarity higher than the (perceived) advantage of collecting dependencies in two places: DESCRIPTION and (more explicitly) NAMESPACE.

Comment: This runs counter to the official advice, of course: "[Using `::`] is slightly less efficient than a formal import and also loses the advantage of recording all dependencies in the `NAMESPACE` file"

Comment: @MichaelChirico Agreed, but even in the case without name clashes I find readability of the source code more important, c.f. my expanded answer.

Comment: I can just comment next to the code which function's being used & still get the efficiency gain of `importFrom`

Comment: @MichaelChirico For me such a comment would constitute a code smell. But that is just my opinion, so I will stop here.